# $_POST variable as value of array

Tags: php, arrays, post

I have problem, that i want to get variable `$_POST` to add to value of an array.
Then i will encode it to json. but the `$_POST` variable didn't give any value.
**EDIT** i did edit the codes:
Here my codes:

```
    <?php
    $temp = isset($_POST['temp']) ? $_POST['temp'] : '';
    $arr["temp_display"] = $temp;
    echo json_encode($arr);
```

and i hope the result will be like this

```
  {"temp_display": value_of_$temp}
```

I try to use same case but I add the value of $_POST to MySQL database and its **Works**.
Here the code:

```
   <?php
    include("connect.php");
    $link=Connection();
    $temp=$_POST["temp"];
    $query = "INSERT INTO `templog` (`temperature`) 
    VALUES ('".$temp."')"; 
    mysql_query($query,$link);
    mysql_close($link);
    ?>
```

**EDIT** Here my jquery code:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {

        setInterval( update, 200);

          function update(){

               var cache = $('.deneme').children();

               $.getJSON('json.php', function(data) {
                $('.deneme').text(data.temp).append(cache);

             })

        }

    });
```

Thank you for Ur help...

Comment: `$arr` id undefined?

Comment: whats the jquery code you used to retrieve date. post that too

Comment: $arr["temp_display"] = isset($_POST['temp']) ? $_POST['temp'] : '';

Comment: @Devs i edited my question for jquery code. Thanks

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yeah undefined, may that the problem? Thanks

Comment: @RahulVyas yeah i've try it but still not working. Thanks

Comment: declare `$arr = []` beforehand

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Your JavaScript is making a GET request and not passing any data at all, so I don't understand why you expect that put to data into `$_POST`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first code block this line `$temp=$_POST["temp"];` is unnecessary as you have done the same thing in the previous line.
You can try by displaying the json data using `var_dump` method like this:

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump(json_encode('$arr');
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: `string(19) "{"temp_display":""}"` The result like this, no value. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $temp = isset($_POST['temp']) ? $_POST['temp'] : '';
  $arr["temp_display"] = $temp;
  echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```